# How to pick columns of table dynamically which are free?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-update, dynamic-programming

Consider following table

```
--------------------------------
ID   | ColA    | ColB   | ColC
--------------------------------
1    | ABC     |        |
2    |         | XYZ    |
3    | PQR     |        |
4    | MNO     | PQR    |
```

Now I have to add a value (EFG) in this table where `ID = 1` in any column like `ColA`, `ColB` or `ColC` depending on which is free (empty). This is done  dynamically or programmatically (consider any language, I just want to know the logic).

For example:

If `ID = 1`, column `ColB` will be updated with value because it's the first free column.
If `ID = 2`, column `ColA` will be updated with value because it's the first free column.
If `ID = 3`, column `ColB` will be updated with value because it's the first free column.
If `ID = 4`, column `ColC` will be updated with value because it's the first free column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since the record is already inserted, you only need to update the row,

```
UPDATE  tableName
SET     ColA = CASE WHEN ColA IS NULL THEN 'NewValue' ELSE ColA END,
        ColB = CASE WHEN ColA NOT NULL AND ColB IS NULL THEN 'NewValue' ELSE ColB END,
        ColC = CASE WHEN ColA NOT NULL AND ColB NOT NULL AND ColC IS NULL THEN 'NewValue' ELSE ColC END
WHERE   ID = 1
```

Comment: `ColC`'s `CASE` statement doesn't check for the state of `ColA`.  If `ColA` is `NULL`, then `'NewValue'` could be stored in both `ColA` and `ColC`, no?

Comment: @JW - If all columns are null, I need to store the NewValue in ColA

Comment: @NareshKumar even if all columns are null this statement will always update `ColA` if `ColA` has not value: `ColA = CASE WHEN ColA IS NULL THEN 'NewValue' ELSE ColA END`

Comment: by the way, What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc.. or both `Oracle` and `SQL Server`

Answer (score 0):

Use this a starting point:

```
UPDATE Table Set 
ColA = CASE WHEN ColA IS NULL THEN 'EFG' ELSE ColA END,
ColB = CASE WHEN ColB IS NULL THEN 'EFG' ELSE ColB END,
ColC = CASE WHEN ColC IS NULL THEN 'EFG' ELSE ColC END
WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: If `ColA`, `ColB`, and `ColC` are all `NULL`, then `'EFG'` will be stored in each of them.  The OP, I think, expects it to be stored in only the first one.

Comment: yes, just noticed that too. Was thinking of updating the answer, but found that JW answered it already

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table
   SET ColA=IF(ColA IS NULL, 'EFG', ColA),
       ColB=IF(ColA IS NULL, ColB, IF(ColB IS NULL, 'EFG', ColB)),
       ColC=IF(ColA IS NULL, ColC, IF(ColB IS NULL, ColC, IF(ColC IS NULL, 'EFG', ColC)))
 WHERE ID=1
```

You don't define what the behavior should be if `ColA`, `ColB`, and `ColC` are all full, but in the example code given above, nothing will change.

Comment: does oracle and/or sqlserver supports `IF`?

Comment: It probably doesn't. I missed those requirements.

Comment: sqlserver could change the If to a CASE WHEN ELSE pretty easily